Where to add css files within django project
I'm building a To Do list in Django by following a tutorial,
I'm trying to make seperate CSS file instead of directly writing it within HTML file, However i'm recieving 404 error.
Below is directory structure
  ├─ base/
  │  ├─ templates/
  │  │  └─ base/
  │  │     ├─ login.html
  │  │     ├─ main.html
  │  │     ├─ register.html
  │  │     ├─ style.css
  │  │     ├─ task_confirm_delete.html
  │  │     ├─ task_form.html
  │  │     ├─ task_list.html
  │  │     └─ task.html
  │  ├─ __init__.py
  │  ├─ admin.py
  │  ├─ apps.py
  │  ├─ models.py
  │  ├─ tests.py
  │  ├─ urls.py
  │  └─ views.py
  ├─ simpletodo/
  │  ├─ __init__.py
  │  ├─ asgi.py
  │  ├─ settings.py
  │  ├─ urls.py
  │  └─ wsgi.py
  ├─ venv/
  ├─ db.sqlite3
  └─ manage.py

Below are files where I'm strying to include css file

main.html

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>To Do List</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <!-- elements from other pages will go here -->
        {% block content %}
        
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
</body>


task_list.html

{% extends 'base/main.html' %} 
{% block content %}
    ** some code **
{% endblock content %}

Only static i've declared is as below

settings.py

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

Follow up - How do I include other files like scripts in a seperate files as well ?
Following other answers i've tried
making a static folder and include css file in that
base/
│
├── static/
│   └── base/
│       └── style.css
│
├── templates/
│   └── base/

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'base/static'),
]


Your static files will be under the /static/ folder (because of your STATIC_URL), so your HTML should look like <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/base/style.css"> or even better <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'base/style.css' %}">. Use the same method for scripts. I would probably create separate css and js folders under base/static/base.
